# Retrieving a value in a view that is passed from HttpPost to HttpGet

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I retrieve the values in the Verify View that I am passing in the Create View. I   want to display these values from the  cshtml file.

```
       [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Verify", ticket);
    }

    [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Verify()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

```
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are passing ticket from cshtml to Create view and then you want that value to pass to Verify view to display in CSHTML ???

Comment: @Guanxi 'yes passing ticket from cshtml to Create view and then you want that value to pass to Verify view to display in CSHTML'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the value in TempData and access it in the verify action and pass it over to your verify view and now you can access the `Ticket` model in verify view. TempData is persisted for the subsequent request. `RedirectToAction` infact does a 302 request to the browser which in turn redirects to the Verify action and you will get the `ticket` from TempData there.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Ticket ticket)
{
    TempData["ticket"] = ticket;
    return RedirectToAction("Verify");
}



[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Verify()
{

    Ticket ticket = (Ticket)TempData["ticket"];
    //Do something
    return View(ticket);
}
```

I don't think it is a good idea to set a complex type in `RouteDataDictionary`.

Comment: Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to . An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\HelpDesk.WebUI\Controllers\HomeController.cs 36 29 HelpDesk.WebUI

Comment: Where you are getting this error? while doing `Ticket ticket = TempData["ticket"];`

Comment: `Ticket ticket = (Ticket)TempData["ticket"];` try this. also verify debugging `TempData["ticket"]` holds the value